# AWS CDK synth and different cdk.json files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

So, I have 3 different cdk.json files with different name/value pairs:   cdk.json,  cdk-west.json  cdk-east.json

When, I run a synth or deploy, can I specify a specific json file instead of the default cdk.json one?

I know you can change profiles with the --profile option, but not sure about cdk.json

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such option.

Comment: Argh! Thanks, I guess I'll just script it to copy the cdk.json over

Comment: Unfortunately, by design CDK does not consider multiple environment in an AWS account such as dev, test, prod and the capability to switch configurations depending on the enviornment, e.g having multiple cdk.json and switch depending on conditions. They assume separation/isolation is to be done per AWS account, or region.

Answer (score 1):

A good way around this is to add an "environment" attribute to your cdk.json file with attributes for each environment that contain settings for that environment.

```
{
...
"environments":{
   "xxxxxxxxxxxx":{
      "name": "dev",
      "awsAccountId":"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "awsRegion":"us-west-2",
      "logLevel":"debug",
      "customSetting": "value 1",
      ...
   },
   "prod-west-1-account-id":{
      "name": "prod-us-west-1",
      ...
   },
   "prod-west-2-account-id":{
      "name": "prod-us-west-2",
      ...
   }
}
```

Then each Stack can grab the appropriate environment configuration based on the value of "this.account"